# I am trying to explode a particular section of a pie chart for a specific field in Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

How can I explode pie chart in **Kendo DataViz**,

my data is coming from database, and my code is like this:

```
dataSource: {
                data: StageData
            },
            title: {
                align: "center",
                text: "Clients by Stage",
                font: "14px Open Sans",
                color: "#3cb2e1"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: false
            },
            series: [{
                type: "pie",
                field: "CountClients",
                aggregate: "sum",
                categoryField: "StageId",
                explodeField: function(){
                                if(categoryField=="Advocate"){
                                    $(this).explode = true;
                                }
                            },
                overlay: {
                    gradient: "none"
                }
```

Here I am trying to explode pie when **categoryField** is "**Advocate**", But this is not working.
Could anyone suggest me how can I achieve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably iterate through the StageData, and set an explode value for each object.

```
$.each(StageData, function(i, s) {
  if(s.StageId === 'Advocate') {
    s.explode = true;
  }
  else {
    s.explode = false;
  }
});
```

Sample... http://jsbin.com/hiqaj/1/edit